# Point location in polygon in R with QGIS files

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, qgis

I have a mapping issue related to QGIS and R. I have a ton of localities(SimplifiedData.csv)  that need to be defined by[regions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5usq.png). The shape files for these marine regions are [QGIS files](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12PvBTNM6FYJKvxTDajbypVI_RIlDJGvG/view?usp=drive_link).

I want to tell whatever function to read this list of longitude and latitudes from [SimplifiedData.csv](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CcINvsGHjgCQra3mBol8KctkpbUfMEA9Uh4oirPTbgc/edit?usp=drive_link) and then spit out what region each locality belongs to into the SimplifiedData files. On the CSV file I have a column that shows the desired outcome

Comment: Many of your points in your data are on land areas, which are not covered by the layers in this OGIS collection (other than by a single layer called "continents"). This appears to be a collection of marine regions, none of which correspond to the regions you are trying to sort your points into. Do you have the right shapefile? What you are asking is possible, but you need shapefiles for the regions you are trying to identify.